# TypeError: randint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'low'

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

```
names = ['Bob', 'Jessica', 'Mary', 'John', 'Mel']
import random
random.seed(500)
random_names = [names[random.randint(low = 0, high = len(names))] for i in range(1000)]
```

Objective is to make a random list of 1,000 names using the five above. But the above code throws back the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#88>", line 1, in <module>
    random_names = [names[random.randint(low = 0, high = len(names))] for i in range(1000)]
TypeError: randint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'low'
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `low` and `high` and your code will work fine. i.e. `random.randint(0, len(names)-1)`

However, more efficient way to do it is using [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
>>> [random.choice(names) for i in range(10)]
['Mel', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'John', 'Bob', 'Mel', 'John', 'Jessica', 'Jessica', 'John']
```

Comment: Removing low and high displays the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#95>", line 1, in <module>
    random_names = [names[random.randint(0, len(names))] for i in range(1000)]
IndexError: list index out of range                                                                     Random.choice works though. Thanks.

Comment: It is due to another issue. You have to use ` len(names)-1` within `randint` because if len of list is `N`, index will be only upto `N-1`

Answer (score 1):

Importing numpy will do it

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(500)

random_names = [names[np.random.randint(low=0,high=len(names))] for i in 

range(1000)]

#Print first 10 records
random_names[:10]
```

The result will be as follow:

```
Out[8]:
['Mary',
 'Jessica',
 'Jessica',
 'Bob',
 'Jessica',
 'Jessica',
 'Jessica',
 'Mary',
 'Mary',
 'Mary']
```